# Two Dimensional Array VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, textbox

Ok so I am having problems adding elements into my 2d array.  I am using 3 textboxes to allow a user to input items into my array. My problem is I cant seem to get the array to go past (0,2). I want the user to be able to add a row of inputs with each click of the add button. This is so far what I have in my code. Can anyone help? This is not for a class I am learning on my own.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1

Private strExams(49, 2) As String

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim strStudent As String = txtStudent.Text
    Dim strTest As String = txtTest.Text
    Dim strScore As String = txtScore.Text
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    If count <= 49 Then
        strExams(count, 0) = strStudent
        strExams(count, 1) = strTest
        strExams(count, 2) = strScore
        count += 1
    End If

    txtStudent.Text = String.Empty
    txtTest.Text = String.Empty
    txtScore.Text = String.Empty

    txtStudent.Focus()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... Your count variable must be placed outside the btnAdd_Click sub or it will always reset back to 0, thus, you won't get past (0,2).

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1

Private strExams(49, 2) As String
Dim count As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

Dim strStudent As String = txtStudent.Text
Dim strTest As String = txtTest.Text
Dim strScore As String = txtScore.Text

If count <= 49 Then
    strExams(count, 0) = strStudent
    strExams(count, 1) = strTest
    strExams(count, 2) = strScore
    count += 1
End If

txtStudent.Text = String.Empty
txtTest.Text = String.Empty
txtScore.Text = String.Empty

txtStudent.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I was sitting here trying to figure that out forever lol